# Syntax error if, elif statements

Tags: python, eclipse, syntax-error

I'm having trouble trying to get this code to work. It keeps coming up with SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
adult = int(input("No adults:")
child = int(input("No children:")
type = int(input("Well done or Rare:")
    if adult < 0:
         print("Enter number >=0)
elif child < 0:
        print("Enter number >=0)
elif type != "W" or type != "R":
       print("error")
```

If the user types in the correct number I want it to go to the next question in line. If user inputs incorrect data I want the error message and then the same question to be repeated.

Thanks!!

Comment: You are missing a double quotes in `print("Enter number >=0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
adult = int(input("No adults:"))
child = int(input("No children:"))
type = int(input("Well done or Rare:"))
if adult < 0:
    print("Enter number >=0")
elif child < 0:
    print("Enter number >=0")
elif type != "W" or type != "R":
    print("error")
```

Compare it with your code.

Your code includes: missing `)`, `"`, bad indentation.

**Note**: Using `type` as a variable will mask the built-in function "type" within the scope of the function or the block which variable is defined within. So while doing so does not raise a SyntaxError, it seems a bad programming experience.

Answer (score 0):

You have some missing brackets:

```
int(input("No adults:")
                       ^
int(input("No children:")
                         ^
int(input("Well done or Rare:")
                               ^ need another to close int()
```

Also, make sure your indentation is correct:

```
if adult < 0:
    print("Enter number >=0)
elif child < 0:
    print("Enter number >=0)
elif type != "W" or type != "R":
    print("error")
```